# Preventing the HERE API returning a bar or pub instead of a railway station

Tags: api, here-maps

When I query for a railway station using HERE API, it returns something in the category "Bar or Pub" instead.

https://browse.search.hereapi.com/v1/browse?at=52.66052,0.16378&limit=5&q=Railway+Station

```
{
  "items": [
    {
      "title": "Railway Road & Station Drive & Victoria Road, Wisbech, PE13 2, United Kingdom",
      "id": "here:cm:node:105932209",
      "resultType": "intersection",
      "address": {
        "label": "Railway Road & Station Drive & Victoria Road, Wisbech, PE13 2, United Kingdom",
        "countryCode": "GBR",
        "countryName": "United Kingdom",
        "state": "England",
        "countyCode": "CAM",
        "county": "Cambridgeshire",
        "city": "Wisbech",
        "district": "Wisbech",
        "streets": [
          "Railway Road",
          "Station Drive",
          "Victoria Road"
        ],
        "postalCode": "PE13 2"
      },
      "position": {
        "lat": 52.65909,
        "lng": 0.15983
      },
      "distance": 310,
      "mapView": {
        "west": 0.15798,
        "south": 52.65797,
        "east": 0.16168,
        "north": 52.66021
      }
    },
    {
      "title": "Station Drive, Wisbech, PE13 2, United Kingdom",
      "id": "here:af:streetsection:EAX7gPFk9wT6b.-75gn.LC",
      "resultType": "street",
      "address": {
        "label": "Station Drive, Wisbech, PE13 2, United Kingdom",
        "countryCode": "GBR",
        "countryName": "United Kingdom",
        "state": "England",
        "countyCode": "CAM",
        "county": "Cambridgeshire",
        "city": "Wisbech",
        "district": "Wisbech",
        "street": "Station Drive",
        "postalCode": "PE13 2"
      },
      "position": {
        "lat": 52.65988,
        "lng": 0.15878
      },
      "distance": 345,
      "mapView": {
        "west": 0.15814,
        "south": 52.65909,
        "east": 0.15983,
        "north": 52.66122
      }
    },
    {
      "title": "Railway Road, Wisbech, PE13 2, United Kingdom",
      "id": "here:af:streetsection:OepxKxcezYPpy4RR9qI72D",
      "resultType": "street",
      "address": {
        "label": "Railway Road, Wisbech, PE13 2, United Kingdom",
        "countryCode": "GBR",
        "countryName": "United Kingdom",
        "state": "England",
        "countyCode": "CAM",
        "county": "Cambridgeshire",
        "city": "Wisbech",
        "district": "Wisbech",
        "street": "Railway Road",
        "postalCode": "PE13 2"
      },
      "position": {
        "lat": 52.65755,
        "lng": 0.16065
      },
      "distance": 392,
      "mapView": {
        "west": 0.15906,
        "south": 52.65643,
        "east": 0.16238,
        "north": 52.65909
      }
    },
    {
      "title": "Railway Bell",
      "id": "here:pds:place:826u125d-d1b6815059144b959e09114b8fda4eec",
      "resultType": "place",
      "address": {
        "label": "Railway Bell, Station Road, Wisbech, PE13 4, United Kingdom",
        "countryCode": "GBR",
        "countryName": "United Kingdom",
        "state": "England",
        "countyCode": "CAM",
        "county": "Cambridgeshire",
        "city": "Wisbech",
        "district": "Wisbech St Mary",
        "street": "Station Road",
        "postalCode": "PE13 4"
      },
      "position": {
        "lat": 52.65684,
        "lng": 0.10071
      },
      "access": [
        {
          "lat": 52.65684,
          "lng": 0.10071
        }
      ],
      "distance": 4273,
      "categories": [
        {
          "id": "200-2000-0011",
          "name": "Bar or Pub",
          "primary": true
        }
      ],
      "references": [
        {
          "supplier": {
            "id": "core"
          },
          "id": "1024347305"
        }
      ],
      "contacts": [
        {
          "phone": [
            {
              "value": "+441945410073"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "title": "MCH",
      "id": "here:pds:place:826u1254-03024f442e2b4dc9ace10cdbf75e64f5",
      "resultType": "place",
      "address": {
        "label": "MCH, Station Approach, March, PE15 8, United Kingdom",
        "countryCode": "GBR",
        "countryName": "United Kingdom",
        "state": "England",
        "countyCode": "CAM",
        "county": "Cambridgeshire",
        "city": "March",
        "district": "March",
        "street": "Station Approach",
        "postalCode": "PE15 8"
      },
      "position": {
        "lat": 52.56011,
        "lng": 0.09123
      },
      "access": [
        {
          "lat": 52.55981,
          "lng": 0.09143
        }
      ],
      "distance": 12192,
      "categories": [
        {
          "id": "400-4100-0035",
          "name": "Railway Station",
          "primary": true
        },
        {
          "id": "400-4100-0042",
          "name": "Bus Stop"
        }
      ],
      "references": [
        {
          "supplier": {
            "id": "core"
          },
          "id": "18115355"
        }
      ],
      "contacts": [
        {
          "phone": [
            {
              "value": "+443457484950"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
{"mode":"full","isActive":false}
```

How do I make sure what gets returned is actually in the categories of what you expect it to be, and not that when you search for "Railway Station" you get some kind of 'Restaurant Railway Station Hotel' or 'Police Station run by Mister Railway' or anything like that.

Comment: the /browse endpoint takes a more machine-oriented or precise interpretation of the request. it uses categories 200-2000-0011 listed here https://developer.here.com/documentation/places/dev_guide/topics/place_categories/category-200-going-out-entertainment.html, for negative (removing Bar or Pub)  use  !200-2000-0011

Comment: @Mapperz What's the correct syntax to append to discover/browse to filter on categories? &cat=!200-2000-0011  doesn't seem to work.

How about Train Station (400-4100-0035) only?

Comment: For /browse examples that show you the correct structure see https://developer.here.com/documentation/geocoding-search-api/dev_guide/topics/endpoint-browse-brief.html (&categories=100-1000-0009) or use the https://developer.here.com/documentation/geocoding-search-api/dev_guide/topics/endpoint-discover-brief.html (more human readable).